# array_key_exists but with an object as the key

Tags: php

What's the best way to check if an object exists as the key of an array?

```
// key: $obj, array: $array
array_key_exists($obj, $array);
```

Results in a PHP Warning: "1st param should be string or integer".

Comment: You could use http://php.net/manual/en/class.splobjectstorage.php.

Comment: if the first param should be a string or integer, why call it an object?  As the answer below states, objects are not array keys, but it looks to me that what you are calling "$obj" has to be a scalar (ie a string or int), not an object (with properties and methods).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects cannot be the keys of an array.

```
<?php

$x = new stdClass;

$y = [$x => 1]; // PHP Warning:  Illegal offset type
```

See https://ideone.com/zR2PXd

You can get some strange stuff that looks like objects are the keys of an array by using the `ArrayAccess` interface, but `array_key_exists` does not work on that.

Answer (score 10):

I'm pretty sure you're wanting [property_exists()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.property-exists.php)

Comment: I don't think this answers OP's question, but it does answer mine... To upvote or not... :)  (I'll upvote!)

Comment: @rinogo same here - brad answered the title, which is first result on google. Another +1 for the answer to the question's title :)

Comment: @rinogo, there is indeed a mismatch between the title and the body of the OPs question.

Answer (score 1):

### Use Like this

```
if(isset($obj->a))
```

### Read carefully this doc.

```
http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

if the property exists, but is not defined isset() will return false.
```